# What does "CV" means in "CV Pad Fitting Instructions"?

Tags: brakes

I am searching the brake service instruction on [ATE site](https://www.ate.co.za/documents.php) and found the abbreviation, that I can't decipher. Apparently, it is opposite to the passenger car, thus it is relative to heavy trucks, buses, etc, but what does **CV** letters stand for?

[image]

Comment: Did you click on the 'View' button? Perhaps the instructions might help explain what 'CV' means in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know this, but after a quick search it looks like it stands for Commercial Vehicle.

e.g. -

https://www.trwaftermarket.com/en/commercial-vehicles/brake-pads-for-commercial-vehicles/

which says - "Europe is the global leader in the Commercial Vehicle (CV) industry and in 2014 vehicle registrations grew by 10.8%, with vans, buses and coaches all increasing significantly"

and

https://www.juratek.com/cv-pads

which says - "xxxxxxx is a leading aftermarket supplier of pads to fit commercial vehicles"

Comment: It seems right.  Also, it can be the "Cargo Vehicle". Does such class exist? But yes, the "Commercial vehicle" name is more common.

Comment: The first link says literally: "Europe is the global leader in the Commercial Vehicle (CV) industry and in 2014 vehicle registrations grew by 10.8%, with vans, buses and coaches all increasing significantly".

Comment: Yes, that is why I added that link.

Comment: The second link for cv-pads says - "xxxxxxx is a leading aftermarket supplier of pads to fit commercial vehicles"